# Handling Avro in ksqlDB without Schema Registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm working with a Kafka deployment which is **not** using any [Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/index.html).
The events in all topics are `Avro`. I have access to the schema, it is just not stored in a `Schema Registry`.

Now, the ksqlDB documentation [explicitly say](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/operate-and-deploy/installation/installing/#installation-instructions) you must have a Schema Registry to be able to handle Avro events:

> Stacks that have Schema Registry can use Avro- and Protobuf-encoded events in ksqlDB applications. Without Schema Registry, your ksqlDB applications can use only JSON or delimited formats.

I'm looking for a workaround to this issue, to be able to define ksqlDB Streams and Tables, on these Avro event topics. I have few ideas, and would like to know if they are valid, or if there is another solution

- Use Kafka API (consumer+producer or stream API) to convert to new topics, from Avro to Json.
- Use a Kafka Connect connector to do the conversion. Most connectors connect into or out of Kafka. The idea here is to connect from one Kafka topic to another. Not sure if possible
- Create some other kind of definition that will let ksqlDB parse the Avro events (Maybe define the ksqlDB stream SQL schema explicitly)

Would like to know ff there are specific example of how to implement any of these.

Comment: Why aren't you using Schema Registry? The reason I ask is that any of your suggested options are a lot more work than just running Schema Registry :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Adding a Schema Registry is not up to me at this point. I have to work with the environment I was given :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, the use of the Schema Registry is **strongly** recommended. It's a standalone JVM deployment (just as ksqlDB is), with the same licence (Confluent Community Licence) as ksqlDB. In fact, at a push, you could even run it on the same machine as ksqlDB.

As well as the fact that it's just easier to run Schema Registry than the solution below, by not using Schema Registry you lose all the benefits of it (compatibility checks, loose-coupling between producer/consumer, etc etc)

---

But, if you absolutely cannot run Schema Registry, then your starting point is understanding how the Avro you have on your Kafka topic has been serialised. If it was with the Schema Registry serialiser (which is how Avro data on Kafka topics usually is) then you will need to deserialise it first using the Schema Registry deserialiser that's available for client libraries (e.g. Java). 
If it's just binary Avro with a separate avsc (which it sounds like it might be) then you just read it as that.

If you want to use the data with ksqlDB then I think your suggestion of reserialising it to JSON is probably the best bet.

So you'd have custom Consumer to read Avro, deserialise using the schema you hold, then custom Producer to write to new Kafka topic as JSON.

From there you can use ksqlDB to read the JSON data, just with the added annoyance of having to manually enter a schema that you already have in Avro ;)

```sql
CREATE STREAM my_source (COL1 VARCHAR, 
                         COL2 BIGINT) 
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='my_json_topic', 
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```